# Client times out when launching XenApp6 app from internet

Tags: citrix, xenapp

Using XenApp6 on Windows 2008 R2 I have the windows Calculator as a test app. Apps are set to run on the server, and are not streamed to the client. When running Calculator from inside the network it runs as expected.

However, when accessing the app from an external web browser or Citrix Receiver, the client always times out and the Calculator app is not launched. I see incoming traffic on port 1494 (which is open) but there is no response from XenApp.

For both internal and external, I log in as Administrator and can see the citrix management console showing my test Calculator app.

Any ideas why it's timing out and not launching from the internet?

Thanks.
Chris

Comment: This is not the right kind of question for stackoverflow. It belongs to serverfault, or, even better, to Citrix's support forums.

Comment: I'm a programmer and citrix is simply the tool used to deploy my application. If I'm having trouble I expect others are in the same boat. And I see plenty of other Citrix questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Citrix server's internal IP is being NATted to an external IP you may need to set an alternate address using `altaddr` on the Citrix server.  Try this: Download the ICA file that the Citrix server passes when you launch a published app from a web browser, open it in a text editor, and see what FQDN or IP it is trying to connect to.

Comment: yep, that was it. the launch.ica was using an internal ip. I wouldn't have known to look in the launch.ica! Thanks.